# Were the language toggles removed from WP recently?

Tags: multi-language, language

I need to change my weblogs language to "English".

I am refering to the article: http://en.support.wordpress.com/language-settings/ which allegedly was "Last modified: July 16, 2012".

I only looked for this option in v.3.4 forward and I cannot find it. 
It's also absent in v.3.5 beta 1. I initially installed and still use the German locale.

Thus:
1). Were these simple drop-down menus removed from more recent versions? Because I can find neither of the two.

2). Could my webhoster be at fault somehow? They offered the "WP One-Click-Install" option, which I thought shouldn't hurt things - I guess I was wrong...

3). Could be my German locale at fault, i.e. maybe only the "international" or "English" version has this toggle, but not any of the downloadable locales? Just a guess.

I am aware of the fact that I can change the language of WP manually, but first I need a clarification what happened to the above feature since July 16th this year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they were never there. The link you posted is for WordPress.com hosted blogs, not self-hosted WordPress.org software.

Refer to [Installing WordPress in Your Language](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language) for info on use in other languages.

Comment: I see. Yet who or what fact does justify the decision of the WP team to make the life for self-hosting bloggers harder, if the same could probably be implemented for .org users? If I would just have to fill in a few lines of information in a GUI it would be simply less tedious than what I find in the link you provide (that I am aware of).